# What's happened to my hats?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022, winterbash-leaderboard

I recently reached 27 hats.

However, on the Winter Bash leaderboard, it displays me as only having 22 hats. Is this caching or a bug? (I had 25 hats yesterday and it was still showing 22 hats.)

Edit: it's not just me, the top users also don't have matching hat counts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your 27 hats are across the entire network, and are indeed visible in the overall leaderboard:

[image]

On the Stack Overflow leaderboard you indeed only have 22 hats because five are your hats weren't earned on Stack Overflow. You have:

- Defender of the Unicorn on Meta Stack Exchange
- Tourist on Meta Stack Exchange, Super User, Writing and Blender
- The Explorer on Meta Stack Exchange and Writing
- This is the Way on Meta Stack Exchange and Writing
- Yes, a Robot on Meta Stack Exchange

If you go to the hat's dialog in your activity page on Stack Overflow, you'll be hinted at this by the fact that these hats have a back background (except for Defender of Unicorn that you're wearing, but if you take it off its background will go back to be white):
[image]